# Android send array from classA to classB

Tags: java, android, arrays

in class A I have a array

```
final Integer[] images = {R.drawable.aa, R.drawable.aa2, R.drawable.aa3, R.drawable.aa4, R.drawable.aa5};
```

I need to send this array to class B and make something like this:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);       
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View viev) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                image.setImageResource(images[0]);
                        }
                });
            Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);       
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View viev) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                image.setImageResource(images[1]);
                        }
        });
```

Comment: the array you want is also accessible from classB

Answer (score 2):

Since Resources are accessible for all the application you dont need to pass the array. Just intialize it in the Class B, IF you don't affect it in Class A.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you  correctly ,you want to pass integer array from one activity to another.
in that can you can try follow code;

```
Intend i = new Intent(A.this,B.class);
i.putIntegerArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<Integer> value);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: No, he said passing to another CLASS, not activity. :)